# How to reuse functions in same controller in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function reuse_user(){

  //get data from table arrival to display
    $data_user['fields'] = array(
         //display feilds
      'id',
      'user_name',
      'user_email',
      'user_psw',
      'user_cpsw',
      'user_designation',
      'usertype_id',
      'user_image'    
    );

    $data_user['order'] = 'id asc';

    //process get data from db
    $data['result_users'] = $this->mod_users->get_users($data_user);

   // var_dump($data['result_users']); die();
}


public function new_appointment(){

    $this->reuse_user();

    $data['related_view']='system_new_appointment';
    $this->load->view('template', $data);

}
```

my reuse_user() function data **not displayed** on view page(system_new_appointment.php)

can i know the correct way to do this?

Comment: $data = $this->reuse_user(); - then pick the data up in view like you usually do it.

Comment: Thanku so much Karlo.It works

Answer (score 2):

`reuse_user` needs to return the `$data` array and the returned array needs to be assigned to the array in the new function... Functions don't know what variables exist in other functions.

```
public function reuse_user(){

  //get data from table arrival to display
    $data_user['fields'] = array(
         //display feilds
      'id',
      'user_name',
      'user_email',
      'user_psw',
      'user_cpsw',
      'user_designation',
      'usertype_id',
      'user_image'    
    );

    $data_user['order'] = 'id asc';

    //process get data from db
    $data['result_users'] = $this->mod_users->get_users($data_user);

   // var_dump($data['result_users']); die();

   return $data;
}


public function new_appointment(){

    $data = $this->reuse_user();

    $data['related_view']='system_new_appointment';
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

---

Or assign the array to the class scope:

```
public function reuse_user(){

  //get data from table arrival to display
    $data_user['fields'] = array(
         //display feilds
      'id',
      'user_name',
      'user_email',
      'user_psw',
      'user_cpsw',
      'user_designation',
      'usertype_id',
      'user_image'    
    );

    $data_user['order'] = 'id asc';

    //process get data from db
    $this->data['result_users'] = $this->mod_users->get_users($data_user);

   // var_dump($data['result_users']); die();
}


public function new_appointment(){

    $this->reuse_user();

    $this->data['related_view']='system_new_appointment';
    $this->load->view('template', $this->data);
}
```